# Is there any functionality similar to "Schema Compliance" and "SOAP Response" as in Ready API in Karate?

Tags: soap, karate

I want to validate SOAP response received in a SOAP API call similar to "SOAP response" in Ready API. And also verify it against a .wsdl file similar to "Schema Compliance" in Ready API. I want to implement these in karate.

What would be the best approach for the same?

Comment: short answer, use java interop and re-use any existing java lib to do wsdl schema validation. wiring this up will be a one-time effort. refer to linked answer for details